# Must emergency exit door safety pins be removed before flight?

Tags: safety

I recently saw while airborne on a flight that the rear right emergency exit door had a pin in it with a red tag stating "REMOVE BEFORE FLIGHT".  The flight was in no rush to depart (had to undergo maintenance for 30min after boarding) so I don't see how it could have been missed.

Is there any reason these should be left in?

Comment: Why do you think it would be "missed"? You were boarding the plane when you saw the tag; the plane wasn't flying yet. Part of the departure procedures would be to remove the pin.

Comment: No, this was mid-flight.

Comment: I suspect OP saw the pin when it is being stored:

https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/4sg7cw/remove_before_flight_safety_pin_still_in_on/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jy0X5H7mjc0

Comment: @Nelson: That's exactly what I saw. I figured there must be some explanation like that because as you can see from the Reddit picture, you cannot miss it. Do you want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see something like this, this is the pin in storage:

[image]

If the pin is in its "deployed" position, it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: @757toga: Yes. The top picture is exactly what it looked like in flight. And it's right outside the bathroom, so I'm sure flight attendants get asked on every flight "shouldn't this be removed before flight?" Ridiculous design.

Comment: Excellent design! By storing it very visibly, you can easily see if it's in the correct position - remember, if it's removed the slide will deploy on opening the door which isn't _great_ on the ground.

Comment: Deploying the slide may be what you want *on the ground*, but it definitely isn't what you want when parked *at the gate!*

Comment: What aircraft type is this? Is it possibly an add on by the airline?